# Orbeon: editing the form data

Tags: orbeon

I want to edit the form submitted by users in Orbeon and our JSP pages is in one WAR file and Orbeon is in another war file under same server i.e. Tomcat

1. I have a Register.JSP file in one war file and where user will click say Register button on Register.jsp
2. After clicking on button it will redirect to another war file of Orbeon New Data form URL (http:/sample.com/orbeon/fr/Registration/Samole/new)
3. User will submit the form by clicking the submit button on form page and be redirected to Successful.jsp of another war file,

   Until now its fine.

   -> If again user wants to edit the form data submitted.  it should redirect to the URL of the form filled by particluar user so that he can edit the form data and update it.

   Let suppose say 100 users submitted the form and 10 users want to edit the form data so how they can edit the data and how we can redirect to URL of form data of particular user so that user can edit and update the form data.

Answer (score 0):

When users submit the data with the `workflow-send` button, the [document id is passed to the success URL](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button) through the `document` request parameter. Knowing the app, form, and document id, your application can point users to the page that allows them back to an Orbeon Forms page that will allow them to edit the data, e.g. `http://host/orbeon/fr/your-app/your-form/edit/document-id`.